# Configure access to GCR for containerd CLI ctr

Tags: google-container-registry, containerd

In the [authentication methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) doc for pulling images from GCR, it only mentioned how to configure access for docker, but I have to use the containerd CLI `ctr` on my **GCE VM**, I cannot use Docker for some reason.

The error was

```
$ sudo ctr images pull gcr.io/<path>

gcr.io/<path>: resolving      |--------------------------------------|
elapsed: 0.3 s                                                     total:   0.0 B (0.0 B/s)                                        
ctr: failed to resolve reference "gcr.io/<path>:latest": unexpected status code [manifests latest]: 401 Unauthorized
```

How do I configure access for it?

**Note that I am not in GKE nor other k8s environment.**

Comment: Hi @Dagang, have you fixed that?

Answer (score 0):

GKE uses the service account configured on the VM instances of cluster nodes to push and pull images, if  cluster and the Container Registry storage bucket are in the same Google Cloud project, the Compute Engine default service account is configured with the appropriate permissions to push or pull images.

you can run a container registry on a GKE cluster using the following command:

```
kubectl run [NAME] --image=[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]:[TAG]
```

to understand what goes in every [] you can go to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-with-google-cloud-platform#gke-run).

If you want to know more about GKE commands you can go [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/)

I hopes this help you

Comment: Thanks but I'm not in GKE nor other k8s env.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON key file based login described here.

[GCR Authentication methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key)

```
ctr images pull -u '_json_key:{  "type": "service_account", ...}' gcr.io/<path>
```